# Listening for Radio Button Deselect Event Without Knowing that Button's Context (Backbone View)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I realize that the issue of the 'change' event not firing for radio buttons on deselect is already widely discussed on this forum (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736782/why-does-jquery-change-not-fire-on-radio-buttons-deselected-as-a-result-of-a)). The standard approach seems to be to listen to the entire radio button group, which generally makes sense.

In my case, however, I am building menu with Backbone consisting of an arbitrary number of views each of which is a radio button with the same name value (e.g. `<input type="radio" name="foo"/>`. Each radio button is instantiated with a Backbone model and I want to bind a setter for one of that model's attributes to fire whenever the radio button is selected/deselected. My current solution is to build the event handlers in the parent view where each radio button is being instantiated but I would prefer not to do this because I don't want to hold on to external references to each radio button view. So the specific question is: "**Is there any way to listen for an individual radio button 'deselect' event without knowing anything about that button's context.**" Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no javascripts events that would provide that functionality, as discussed in the link you included. For good reasons!

Radio buttons are really meant to be taken as a group, separating them in multiple backbone views doesn't really make sense to me, it'd be like having a backbone view for each option of a select and then wondering how to make them aware of each other's status!

So... AFAIK, there is no clean way. But obviously, you can always bind to the this.$el.parent().on("change", ...) and then in the event handler, compare your input view's value to the old value to detect if it was deselected. You can have an event handler in the parent view to save the previous value in the parent element's data. Technically, the child view wouldn't really be aware of the surrounding child elements, and the handler that update the model would be in the child view, but the child view needs to be aware of its container (the parent view) to bind on the change event and to get the old value (to know if the child was deselected). Fair enough?

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Alternative I also found was that I wanted to create the event listener before embedding the view in the DOM, so solution was to bind `$('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').trigger('deselect');` as an event listener to `change input[type=radio]:checked` and then add a second listener for `deselect input[type=radio]:not(:checked)`. Any time a radio button is selected it triggers a deselect event in the others and then you can listen for that.

Answer (score 3):

The event is not supplied by the browser, but you can create it easy enough:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type=radio]:checked')
$('input[type=radio]')
  .click(function() {
    checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').trigger('deselect');
    checkboxes = $('input[type=radio]:checked')
  })
```

Then to use you just simply add

```
$('#mycheckbox').bind('deselect', function () {
    alert('Deselected');
}
```

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/edvpt6au/3/

Comment: Thanks Luke. See my similar answer as a comment to the accepted answer above :)