# jquery in yii: Detecting radiobutton losing check mark (checked state)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii

Given the following code (yes, i know it is perhaps irrelevant in yii, but I added the tag so I update the question with the actual generated html):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#widgetId-form input[name="valueType"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            console.log("habilitando "+$(this).data("class"));
            $("."+$(this).data("class")).prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("deshabilitando "+$(this).data("class"));
            $("."+$(this).data("class")).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }).change();
});
</script>
<div id="widgetId-dialog">
<form id="widgetId-form" action="/support/test" method="post">
    <div>
        <input id="valueType-single" value="single" data-class="singleValueField" checked="checked" type="radio" name="valueType" />
        <label for="single">Valor simple</label>
        <input size="6" class="singleValueField" type="text" value="" name="singleValue" id="singleValue" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="valueType-range" value="range" data-class="rangeValueField" type="radio" name="valueType" />
        <label for="range">Rango (inicio:fin:intervalo)</label>
        <input size="6" class="rangeValueField" type="text" value="" name="rangeValue_start" id="rangeValue_start" />:<input size="6" class="rangeValueField" type="text" value="" name="rangeValue_end" id="rangeValue_end" />:<input size="6" class="rangeValueField" type="text" value="" name="rangeValue_interval" id="rangeValue_interval" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

It doesn't trigger change() when a radio becomes unchecked. This implies: controls are disabled **only on initialization (.ready())**. change() is not triggered individually by controls losing the checkmark.

**Question**: how can I detect when a radio button loses the checkmark?

Comment: have you tried appending an on to "widgetId-dialog" ? https://api.jquery.com/on/  `$("#widgetId-dialog").on('change', 'input[name="valueType"]', function() ......`

Comment: May be a dumb question, but is that code as written? As it stands the javascript could be executing before the HTML is drawn.  Try wrapping it in a `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: @stakolee `$(function(){` == `$(document).ready()` ..same thing

Comment: from jquery doc: "This method is a shortcut for .on( "change", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "change" ) in the third."

Comment: Do you use any jquery plugin to customize your radio buttons, or any indirect changing of the radio's state other then clicking the native input directly. Because when thats the case the radio change function wont fire, you have to fire it manually.

Comment: the full code is what you see. in my case i'm using yii and, unless explicitly told, it does not import anything else via the default controllers and layouts.

Comment: Once a radio button in a group gets checked, you cannot uncheck the group - at least one in the group remains checked. Are you asking how to detect when the radio button group value changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conceptional problem. The radio buttons are seen somehow like one element. For closer information look at [Why does jQuery .change() not fire on radio buttons deselected as a result of a namesake being selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736782/why-does-jquery-change-not-fire-on-radio-buttons-deselected-as-a-result-of-a). 
So the change-event will always only fire on the newly selected element and not on the deselected radios. You could fix your code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#widgetId-form input[name="valueType"]').change(function(){
        //could be also hardcoded : 
        $('input[name="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]').each(function(){
                 if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                console.log("habilitando "+$(this).data("class"));
                $("."+$(this).data("class")).prop("disabled", false);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("deshabilitando "+$(this).data("class"));
                $("."+$(this).data("class")).prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
    });

    $('#widgetId-form input[name="valueType"]:first').change();
});
```

You can check it at http://jsfiddle.net/jg6CC/. Greets another Luis M. ;)

Comment: if you got many radios you could remember the last selected radio and apply changes on this and on newly selected radio. This way there would be no need to iterate through all (and save performance..even if you should not get performance issues with iterating)

Comment: I solved in a way similar to the described here (i gave up, and reached the same conclusion). However it's silly to me that HTML radios don't trigger change() for radio buttons being unselected (in that sense, remembering the previous radio would not be needed at all).